# Two sample t-test vs regression

Tags: regression, forecasting, t-test, mean, median

I would like to examine the difference in forecast error between year 1 and 2. The descriptive statistics show that the mean of forecast error is higher in Year 2 but the median is lower. Under what circumstance would this happened?

Also, when I test this in the following regression after controlling for other factors, $\beta_1$ is negative and significant, which means forecast error in Year 2 is significantly lower than Year 1. However, This result is inconsistent with the descriptive statistics result. How do I interpret that? Under what circumstance would the regression direction completely opposite to the t-test direction?

$Error = \alpha + \beta_1Year + \text{Control variables}$

where: $Year$ is a dummy variable (year 2 is $1$, & year 1 is $0$).

Comment: Why look at mean forecast error or median forecast error. Neither one is a measure of forecast accuracy.  The mean only estimates bias.  The slope of the regression line being negative means that the estimate decreases going from year one to year two. It says notthing about forecast error.  I downvoted this question because you are either very confused about forecast error or you are explaining your question with incorrect terminology.

Answer (score 3):

A t-test does not control for the "other factors" that you say you controlled for in the regression. So, they ask two different questions and get two different answers. After controlling for control variables, the "forecast error" (but see @Michael 's comment) went down in year 2; without controls, it went up.

Since you don't provide any context we can't say what this means. However, an example where it might be true is if the dependent variable is income, one independent variable is year and you have two samples of people. Income might go up from year 1 to year 2, uncontrolled, but go down if (say) age and ethnic group are controlled for.

Comment: +1 - I hadn't noticed the reference to control variables in the OP.

Answer (score 1):

If the mean of the second group of data (it doesn't matter that they are forecast errors, let's just treat them as a bunch of data) is higher than the first group, then a regression where "group" is your only explanatory variable should also show that.  In simple situations, an ordinary least squares regression reduces exactly to comparing the means.  So, there are no circumstances when the t-test direction would be opposite to a simple one variable regression.

*(edit, having read Peter Flom's answer and re-read the question)*.  Either the issue comes about because of your "control variables" in the regression (which can easily result in the sign of an estimated coefficient changing once they are introduced), or you have made a data management error.

On the other hand, there are many situations when the mean would give a different finding to the median.  Presumably you have a few high individual errors in year 2 which bring up the mean but have no impact on the median.  Generally, I would recommend using a trimmed mean, which can be seen as a sort of compromise between a median and a mean (a median is just a 50% trimmed mean).  But most important is that you sort out what leads to the contradictory result between your t test and regression.